# Root folder change (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my "public_html" directory I have the following structure:

```
- root
  - index.html
  - blog
    - index.html
- lab
  - index.html
- wp
  - (WORDPRESS FILES)
```

The "lab" and "wp" directories are just subdomain directories ("http://lab.tomblanchard.co.uk" and "http://wp.tomblanchard.co.uk") which work fine.

Basically I want the main domain ("http://tomblanchard.co.uk") to point to the "root" directory without any actual redirecting, for example, I want "http://tomblanchard.co.uk" to point to the "index.html" file within the "root" directory, I want "http://tomblanchard.co.uk/blog" to point to the "index.html" file within the "root/blog" directory and so on.

I have kind of achieved this with the following code in my ".htaccess" file:

```
#  Add directives
RewriteEngine on

#  Remove ".html" extension from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

#  Change root directory to "root" folder
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)root 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ root/$1 [L]
```

The only problem is that things like "http://tomblanchard.co.uk/root/" and "http://tomblanchard.co.uk/root/blog/" still work when really they shouldn't even be able to be accessed (404).

If anyone has any idea on how to sort this or has a stronger method of doing this it would be greatly appreciated.

***Update***

Finally got it working how I wanted it after hours of researching, I used the following:

```
#  Add directives
RewriteEngine on

#  Change root directory to "root" folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /root/
RewriteRule ^root/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^root/ root%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Maybe use VHosts instead.

Comment: Look up use of the http.conf file in your apache installation. You can set up vhosts to point to any directory for any domain

Answer (score 1):

The order of directives in mod_rewrite is important, as each rule sees the output of the previous rule as its input to test. You need to do 3 (or possibly 4) things, in order:

1. Deny access to any URL beginning `/root/` (we have to do this first, else *everything* will be denied!)
2. It's generally good practice to ensure each URL has only one valid form, so URLs which *do* specify `.html` should cause a browser redirect to the non-`.html` form. This needs to happen *before* other rewrites, otherwise you can't tell the difference between a .html from the browser and one you've added virtually.
3. Look up any URL not denied above in the `/root/` directory, rather than the configured `DocumentRoot`
4. Look up any URL not pointing at a directory under the URL + `.html`, if that file exists. This has to come *after* other rewrites, or the "file exists" check will always fail.

```
#  General directives
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Deny URLs beginning /root/, faking them as a 404 Not Found
RewriteRule ^root/ [R=404]

# Additional rule to strip .html off URLs in the browser
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=permanent,L]

# Rewrite everything remaining to the /root sub-directory
# (Host condition was in your post originally, then edited out; this is where it would go)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tomblanchard\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ root/$1

# Handle "missing" ".html" extension from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

PS: Note my careful language to describe (internal) rewrites, as opposed to (browser) redirects: the rule you have is not *removing* `.html` from anything, it is *adding* it, thus allowing the page to be accessed *if* someone else removes it. Since you are often modifying both within a set of rules, it's important to keep clear in your head the distinction between the URL the browser has requested, and the virtual URL Apache will ultimately serve.

Comment: Isn't it better to put `RewriteBase /` up there? And I've noticed something like `^root/` doesn't get recognized in my server so I wrote something like `.root` for one of my projects. I just wanted to say this because one time it caused me headaches.

Comment: @MahanGM Depending on the exact context, the URL string being matched either does or does not contain the first leading `/`; I'm used to having access to the actual `VirtualHost` definition rather than an `.htaccess` file; you're probably right that `RewriteBase` may be necessary/useful. As for `.root`, that will match the string "root" anywhere **except** the start of the URL (since you are only requiring that there be one character before it); you probably want `^/?root` or just `^root`.

Comment: Hey, really appreciate the work you've put into this @IMSoP, I've just tested it out and as you can see, every page is just a 404 unfortunately, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining any rule to block `/root` address so how do you want to block it when there is nothing to do that?

Try this:

```
#  Add directives
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .root [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) / [L,R=404]

#  Remove ".html" extension from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

#  Change root directory to "root" folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tomblanchard.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tomblanchard.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.root
RewriteRule (.*) /root/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

This is not tested so if it wouldn't work, play around with it to get your need.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but this just gives me a 404 at every page under the domain.

Comment: As I've mentioned this is not tested but I'll explain why it's behaving like this. First off, when you reach to redirect `http://tomblanchard.co.uk/` and `http://tomblanchard.co.uk/blog` to root directory, it then assumes that you're in `root` directory and when it reaches to rule that blocks `root` direct access, it shows you nothing. Because it knows you are there.

Comment: Rewriting to a file called `404.html` is not the correct way of causing a 404 - it will still return status 200, as though the URL was valid. Instead, use an appropriate rewrite flag, such as [`R=404`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r), [`F`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f), or [`G`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_g).

Comment: @IMSoP yeah sure, I just wanted to route it to a custom page for ease.

Comment: @MahanGM Then either that custom page would need to be a server-side script (e.g. a PHP file) which can over-ride the status code, or more likely, you use the [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive to handle *all* 404s, regardless of whether you created them artificially with a rewrite rule.

Comment: @IMSoP I just wanted to show how this can happen, nothing more dude. Chill out.

Comment: @MahanGM Apologies, no non-chilled-nessed intended, just trying to spread knowledge. :|

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for your concern. No offense has happened.